# find minimum numbers of currency for required amount

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, for-loop, stackblitz

I made a little program to find minimum number of notes(currency) for the required amount. for example, let's say I enter an **amount 1121** and I have an array of these values below:
**notes** = [1, 2, 5, 10, 50, 100, 200, 500] so my final result will be:

500 * 2(notes) = 1000

100 * 1 = 100

20  * 1 = 20

1   * 1 =  1

then the total would be **1121**. any help with understanding would be much appreciated. I know it only takes one for loop but I'm confused in some parts.

here's what I did: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rufwzk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: What problem are you having with your code? Im not sure what the question is...

Comment: which parts are you confused with?

Comment: i want to store the amount of each value and its quotient to check if it's equal to entered amount or not 

**entered amount:** 1121

array = [1, 2, 5, 10, 50, 100, 200, 500];

starting from reverse

1)  1121 / 500 = 500 * 2 = 1000, remainder 121 and quotient is 2

2) 121 / 200 not possible

3) 121 / 100 = 100 * 1 = 100, remainder 21 and quotient is 1

4) 21 / 50 not possible

5) 21 / 10 = 10 * 2 = 20, remainder is 1 and quotient 2

6) 1 / 5 not possible

my final result is 
which currency note: 500, 100, 10
number of each currency: 2, 1, 2 (quotients)

Comment: @user184994 my question is i want to console each currency note and its repeated numbers. consider an array as currency array.

e.g entered amount 1000 then i would require 500rs note 2 times.

Comment: @confusedGuy please enter all the explanations in you post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code of what you want. I hope i get it right.

```
  requiredNotes(amount) {
    let noteArry = this.notes,
      quotient,
      remainder,
      temp,
      noteCount = 0,
      eachNote,
      remainingAmount = 0;
    for (let i = noteArry.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (amount >= noteArry[i]) {
        quotient = Math.floor(amount / noteArry[i]);
        remainder = amount % noteArry[i];
        amount = amount - (noteArry[i] * quotient);
        if (amount == 0) {
          console.log("note:-", noteArry[i], ",number of note", quotient);
          break;
        } else if (amount != 0) {
          console.log("note:-", noteArry[i], ",number of note", quotient);
        }
      } else {
                continue;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: yes, exactly. it was so simple. now i feel stupid. thanks a bunch. i was really stuck at remainingAmount part.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let i = noteArry.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (amount >= noteArry[i]) {
    quotient = Math.floor(amount / noteArry[i]);
    remainder = amount % noteArry[i];
    remainingAmount = noteArry[i] * quotient;
    amount=amount-remainingAmount;
    console.log('number of notes =', noteArry[i], 'x', quotient,' notes');
  }
}
```

This does the trick simply logs out the number of notes for the mentioned amount.

Comment: yes, I was stuck at comparing remainingAmount with original. now it seems simple.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified a little your code (using JS Map):

```
...
notesMap = new Map();
...

requiredNotes(amount) {
  for (let i = this.notes.length - 1; i >= 0 && amount; i--) {
    const qty = Math.floor(amount / this.notes[i]);
    qty && this.notesMap.set(this.notes[i], qty);
    amount = amount % this.notes[i];
  }

  const entries = Array.from(this.notesMap.entries());
  this.requireNotes = entries.map(([curr, qty]) => `${curr} * ${qty} = ${curr * qty}`);
}
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z33pkp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)